# Retrieving a list of Tridion 2009 components with a specific value and schema without using search

Tags: tridion, tridion2009

I would like to create a .NET page residing on the CMS server that shows all components that are based on a specific Schema(tcm:3-3-8) and from a specific Publication(tcm:0-3-1) including BluePrinted and Localized items, but only if they have the value "http://www.google.com" for the field "URL" in that Schema.

Is this possible, without using the search service as this is rather slow and unreliable?

Comment: You should get someone to check your search setup then, it _is_ supposed to work, even if it does use Verity/Autonomy/HP software (in 2009)...

Comment: This is exactly what the search interface is built for (as it created an index of all the data you need for fast  retrieval). Please don't reinvent the wheel because something is not configured correctly in your implementation.

Answer (score 2):

Your search might be slow because of not indexing the search collection.

You should do indexing the search collection on regular intervals for better and fast results.

Comment: So is search the only way to do this, that`s fine if it`s the only way, I agree search should be fixed anyway?

Answer (score 1):

That's an expensive operation to do because of the cost of opening each individual component to check the value of a field, but certainly do-able.

1. Get the schema object
2. Get a list of components that use this schema (WhereUsed on the schema with filter on ItemType = component)
3. Open each component and check the value for the field(s), add to a `List<Component>` if it matches
4. Display list (possibly using a ASP.NET GridView)

Answer (score 0):

I have not had any chance to test it, but something like this

```
    Common common = new Common();
    TDSE tdse = new TDSE();
    ListRowFilter ComponentFilter = tdse.CreateListRowFilter();



    Schema schema = (Schema)common.getObject("tcm:126-238630-8", ItemType.ItemTypeSchema);
    ComponentFilter.SetCondition("ItemType", ItemType.ItemTypeComponent);
    ComponentFilter.SetCondition("Recursive", true);

    XDocument doc = common.ReadXML(schema.Info.GetListUsingItems(ListColumnFilter.XMLListID, ComponentFilter));
    List<Component> MatchedComponents = new List<Component>();

    XmlNamespaceManager NS = new XmlNamespaceManager(new NameTable());
    NS.AddNamespace("tcm", "http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0");
    NS.AddNamespace("Content", "uuid:4432F3C3-9F3E-45E4-AE31-408C5C46E2BF");
    foreach (XElement component in doc.XPathSelectElements("/tcm:ListUsingItems/tcm:Item", NS))
    {
        Component comp = common.getComponent(component.Attribute("ID").Value);

        XDocument compDoc = common.ReadXML(comp.GetXML(XMLReadFilter.XMLReadData));
        foreach (XElement compNode in compDoc.XPathSelectElements("/tcm:Component/tcm:Data/tcm:Content/Content:Content/Content:feederUrl", NS))
        {
            MatchedComponents.Add(comp);
        }
    }
```